# Can I find adjacent duplicates of a specific character in a string?

Tags: python, string, duplicates, character

How can I find adjacent duplicates of a specific character in a string? And then delete some of the duplications but not all.

Let's say I have:

```
`str= "KKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLOOOPPPPLLL"`
```

The only duplicated letter I'm interested in is `L`. I would like to reduce `L` adjacent duplications -> if `L` is part of a line of 15 adjacent duplications, I want it to lose 5 adjacent duplicates. If it is in a line of 3, I want it to lose 1 `L`

Final output should be:

`KKKKKLLLLLLLLLLOOOPPPPLL`

Sorry if this makes very little sense, hopefully you understand what I mean. Any help would be hugely appreciated!!

EDIT: It won't always be reduced by one third, or by the same fraction.

Final note for clarification. My end game: There will be a randomly generated string with a length of a few hundred. The lengths of the duplications will decide how much it needs to reduced by, which is half or less than half. So a line of 50 'L', will need to be reduced by <=25 . A line 64 reduced by <=32. But not reduced by 0. This just seems incredibly complicated to…

Comment: What if you have 2 or 14 which are not multiples of 3?

Comment: Will the number of Ls always be a multiple of 3?

Comment: So you want to reduce it to two thirds?

Comment: No it won't always be reduced by multiples of 3

Comment: "So a line of 50 'L', will need to be reduced by <=25." 1 <= 25. Does that mean you can reduce it by 1 L? How about by 0?

Comment: Yes it can be reduced by 1 L … Not by 0. I didn't even think of that

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
original="KKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLOOOPPPPLLL"
expected="KKKKKLLLLLLLLLLOOOPPPPLL"
original=original.replace("LLL","LL")
print(len(expected))        #24
print(len(original))        #24
print(original==expected)   #True
```

New edit:

```
import math
import re
s="KKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLOOOPPPPLLL"
expected="KKKKKLLLLLLLLLLOOOPPPPLL"
a=[]
for it in re.finditer("L+",s):
    a.append(it.span())
for p in reversed(a):
        l=p[1]-p[0]
        s=s[:p[0]]+"L"*round(l*2/3)+s[p[1]:]
print(s)
print(expected)
print(s==expected)
```

New edit2: as per [@wwii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41799235/5033247)

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
s="KKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLOOOPPPPLLL"
s="".join("".join(k)*(len(list(g))*2//3) if k=='L' else "".join(g) for k,g in gb(s))
```

New edit3:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
s1="KKKKKLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLOOOPPPPLLL"
s=""
for k,g in gb(s1):
    if k=='L': 
        s+="".join(k)*(len(list(g))*2//3) 
    else:  
        s+="".join(g)
print(s)
```

Comment: ```str.join``` will consume a generator expression, no need to make a list.  The process in that list comprehension is probably easier to read if it is *unwound*

Comment: @SmartManoj Thanks for your answer. It wasn't totally what I was looking for, but I was able to make a few changes to your 'New edit' and that made it possible. You're awesome

Answer (score 0):

- Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the string into contiguous duplicates and iterate over it;
- make a list of the group
- If the key for the group is `'L'`, get the length of the list and divide it by 3, use this number to slice the list
- add the list to a `result` container
- convert the container to a string